# When pressing Enter key page doesn't redirect

Tags: jquery, forms, passwords, redirect

I have a PDF file that is downloadable after typing a password. If the password is wrong it redirects the user to another page called incorrect.html.

The problem is that it only works when you click the Submit button. When you press the Enter Key it doesn't work

How can this be fixed?

```
<form name="login">
<input class="gen-label" type="text" name="pass" size="17" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;">
<input class="button submit" type="button" value="Submit"  onClick="TheLogin(this.form)">
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
function TheLogin() {
var password = 'pass1';
if (this.document.login.pass.value == password) {
  top.location.href="path_to_PDF.pdf";
}
else {
  location.href="incorrect.html";
  }
}
```

**Fiddle**
http://fiddle.jshell.net/HKLma/

Comment: Why don't you use `onsubmit` event of form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;"
```

with

```
onkeyup="if(event.which === 13) TheLogin(this.form);"
```

or replace all the inline JS with

```
$('[name="login"]').on('submit', function() {
    var password = 'pass1';
    if ( $('[name="pass"]').val() == password) {
        top.location.href="path_to_PDF.pdf";
    } else {
        location.href="incorrect.html";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('.gen-label').keyup(function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 13)
{
    $(this).trigger(".button submit");
}});
```

**[Working Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/HKLma/1/)**